# Creating array of timetables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, timetable

I am attempting to do some analysis on a series of `timetable` objects. Each has a potentially different date range (they represent observations of a time series). I would like to pass this array of `timetable` objects into a function.

Using the `quandl` addon:

```
>> conn = quandl(<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>);
>> z1 = history(conn, 'ZILLOW/M1300_MPPRSF');
>> z2 = history(conn, 'ZILLOW/M1300_MPPRAH');
```

Then attempting to take these two time series and group them into an array (*NOT* join them together):

```
>> [z1, z2]
Duplicate table variable name: 'Value'.
```

Is there a method to do this such that I could save a number of `timetables` into a vector so that I can iterate over them without using `varargin` in the function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate two timetables horizontally if the names of the variables are identical.
I suggest you create a cell array of timetables and use that instead.

```
>> {z1 z2}
```

You might find [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types.html) doc page on datatypes useful.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a cell array of the timetables and then use a `cellfun` to perform your analysis. For example, if you would like to perform the `lag` calculation on the timetables, you could do the following:

```matlab
myData = {z1, z2};
myLags cellfun(@lag, myArray);
```